# HTML5, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем доброго времени суток.
Кто знает подскажите, как удалить изображение которое было помещено на холст?

```
<html>
<META charset='UTF8'>
<head>
  <title>imgExample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="Delete()">Удалить изображение</a>

<br/>

  <canvas id='example' width="1000" height="750">
       <img src="2.png" width="50" height="70" id="IdIMG"/>
  </canvas>

  <script>
  function Delete(){

$("#IdIMG").remove();//удаление не срабатывает

  } 
    var example = document.getElementById("example");
    var ctx = example.getContext('2d');  // Контекст холста
    var pic = new Image();

    pic.onload = function() {
    var img=document.getElementById("IdIMG");
        ctx.drawImage(img,1,1);
    }
  </script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: никак. вы нарисовали картинку, она стала набором пикселей на холсте.  
если вы можете перерисовать всю сцену, то по кнопке delete сотрите все и рисуйте заново без картинки.

Comment: А можно ли как-то привязать событие к определённому участку?

Comment: События точно такие же как для других элементов. img, div, canvas... Т.е. берете mousemove и считаете координаты, на mousedown и mouseup делаете какие-то действия с полученными ранее координатами. При этом каждое действие приводит к перерисовке всего холста либо какого-то участка, который надо перерисовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаление `#IdIMG` и не поможет, оно удалит картинку-источник, которую `ctx.drawImage` использовало для рисования на холсте. (Правда, в коде `pic.onload` никогда не выполнится, т.к. `pic` пустое, так что и рисования никогда не будет.) Результат рисования, от этого, разумеется, не изменится.

Удалить нельзя, почти так же, как нельзя удалить мазок краской по холсту — это не объект, который можно перемещать или удалять, это просто точки. Разве что можно очистить через `ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 50, 70);`

Comment: А можно ли как-то привязать событие к определённому участку?

Comment: Могу лишь посоветовать Вам использовать замечательную библиотеку KinectJS http://www.kineticjs.com